# Why am I getting a 404 page when being sent back from worldpay?

Tags: magento, worldpay

Im installing WorldPay on a Magento site and Im having an issue with the callback:

A user buys a product, fills out the address and delivery info, pay via WorldPay, get directed to WorldPay, enter card details and then get fired back to the website BUT they are getting fired back to /checkout/worldpay/success/ when I need them to be sent to /checkout/onepage/success I could use a url rewrite for this but questioning if its the correct way to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in Phonenix Worldpay source there is an **success** action in **processing** controller, which in fact should redirect user to */checkout/onepage/success* when no exception occurs.

```
/**
 * Worldpay return action
 */
public function successAction()
{
    try {
        $session = $this->_getCheckout();
        $session->unsWorldpayRealOrderId();
        $session->setQuoteId($session->getWorldpayQuoteId(true));
        $session->setLastSuccessQuoteId($session->getWorldpaySuccessQuoteId(true));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success');
        return;
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_getCheckout()->addError($e->getMessage());
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        $this->_debug('Worldpay error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
```

However some people reported problems with redirection in WorldPay after upgrade.

What magento version, and have you upgraded recently?
Any errors in system.log??

Comment: Im using magento 1.9.0, and know just started on 1.9.0

Comment: changed the $this->_redirect('checkout/worldpay/success'); to $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success'); and it worked !!

Answer (score 1):

Magento default url:
domain.com/modulename/controllername/actionname

So possibly the worldpay Extension adds something like

`app/code/community/Mage/Checkout/controllers/WorldpayController.php`

or

`app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/WorldpayController.php`

and This controller have possibly an action called successAction()
and maybe there is a redirect that ends up in an 404